# How to connect IF in my ELSE condition inside of while?

Tags: c++, while-loop

C++
I'm stuck my if and else is not connecting

error: else without previous if

```
#include<iostream>

int main(){
    int i=1, num, sum=0;
    while (i <= 5) {
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin>>num;

        if (num % 2 ==0 ){
           sum = sum + num;
           i++;}
           cout<<"\nThe sum is " << sum;
           }


       else{
         sum=sum*num;
         i++;
         cout<<"\nThe product is"<<sum; }
}
}
```

> How to connect if in my else condition inside of while?

Comment: Check your parenthesis

Comment: I need to build a program that will let the user enter five numbers and display the product of odd inputted numbers and the sum of even inputted numbers using a while loop.

I don't really know if I build the correct program

Comment: Format your code properly.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on. The problem here seems to be *entirely* a product of the confused indentation.

Comment: The presence of not just one, but **two** instances of "enter code here" suggests that the copying/pasting and proofreading leaves something to be desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem here is indentation and structure, which is easily fixed by writing it in idiomatic C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// Avoid using namespace std; as that separation exists for a reason

int main() {
  int sum = 0;

  // Use a for() loop instead of while(n < L) { ... n++ }
  // Declare iterator variables inside the scope in which they're used
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    // Declare variables individually if/when they are needed
    int num;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
    std::cin >> num;

    if (num % 2 == 0) {
      sum += num; // x += y -> x = x + y

      std::cout << "The sum is " << sum << std::endl;
    }
    else {
      sum *= num; // x *= y -> x = x * y

      std::cout << "The product is " << sum << std::endl;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Where the key is to use `for()` instead of the inappropriate `while()`.

> Tip: When writing code, *structure* as conveyed by indentation and formatting is *extremely* important. You should be able to see at a glance what's going on without having to read and parse the code on a syntax level.

> Tip: When you're faced with a perplexing syntax problem or a bug, if you get stuck spend that time organizing your code to be more clear and understandable. Improve variable names. Organize things into functions where appropriate. Break down your problem until it becomes clear what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks for answering my stupid question and thanks a lot for noticing my indentation and structure now I know where I'm working on

Comment: Nothing "stupid" about it. Learning is all about making mistakes. Upvote any answers that help, and when ready, accept the one that solves your problem. Helps steer others towards solutions as well.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here` is a syntax error.  The code is poorly formatted so it's hard to see that the else lines up with the while loop which is also invalid syntax.  You have an `if` statement then a `count`.  You cannot have any statements between if and else.  You probably want something like this:

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;
  
  
  int main() {
          int num, val = 0;
          for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                  cout << "Enter a number: ";
                  cin >> num;
                  if(num % 2) {
                          val *= num;
                          cout << "\nThe product is" << val;
                  } else {
                          sum += num;
                          cout << "\nThe sum is " << val;
                  }
          }
          return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When properly formatted, your code looks like the following:

```
int i=1, num, sum=0;

while (i <= 5) 
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> num;

    if (num % 2 == 0)
    {
        sum = sum + num;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "\nThe sum is " << sum;
}
else
{ 
    sum=sum*num;
    i++;
}

cout<<"\nThe product is"<<sum;
}
}
```

As you can see, the `else` you wrote is connected to the `while` statement, not the `if` statement. You also have two extra right curly braces at the bottom. I have removed the `enter code here` lines, since I don't think they're in your original code. If they are, you should be getting a syntax error.